# Calculate one year expiry date from current date in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

What would be the best way to calculate one year expiry date from current date in oracle?
PS : Need to consider leap year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select (sysdate + interval '1' year ) from dual
```

**update** (see Justin Cave's comment)

```
select decode( to_char(sysdate, 'mmdd'), 
               '0229', 
               (sysdate-1) + interval '1' year, 
               (sysdate + interval '1' year ))
 from dual;
```

Comment: @A.B. Cade - Be careful about adding year & month intervals to a date.  If you add a year to Feb 29, 2008, the result will be an exception, not Feb 28, 2009.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this query

```
 select add_months(to_date('08/12/2011','dd/mm/yyyy'),12) from dual;
```

Comment: be carefull with that one: a-it's not ANSI; b- if youl try add_months(to_date('28/02/2011', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 12) you'll get **29**/02/20012 and not **28**/02/2012 as expected

Comment: @A.B.Cade - True.  But that's generally better than getting an exception (ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified) when you add a 1 year interval to February 29, 2012

Comment: @Justin Cave - IMHO, it's better to get an exception than have wrong data

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT current_date + INTERVAL '1' YEAR FROM dual;
```

Read about the [pros and cons in this thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1157035034361). Adding `INTERVAL '1' YEAR` can fail for Feb. 29th. Thanks to @Justin for the hint.
(It wouldn't fail in PostgreSQL where you get Feb. 28th instead for non-leap years.)

[Interval Literals in the Oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221).

Comment: @EErwin - Be careful about adding year & month intervals to a date.  If you add a year to Feb 29, 2008, the result will be an exception, not Feb 28, 2009.